# PHP 5 to 7 migration - Numbers comparison

Tags: php, php-7

I noticed that code below results in different messages in PHP 5.x and 7:

```
if ('0xFF' == 255) {
    echo 'Equal';
} else {
    echo 'Not equal';
}
```

- 5.x: Equal
- 7: Not equal

Tried to find a description of the changes that cause it in migration guide and in the PHP doc but couldn't find anything. Probably it is somewhere there and I just missed it. Can you, please, point it? Thank you!

Where I looked

- http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: [that's exactly why I always hated languages with implicit type conversions between string/numeric/boolean etc. and type-converting comparisons](http://i.stack.imgur.com/35MpY.png) - [guess what, each language of those has its own rules, because all the other are stupid, duh](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's here: http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php

> Changes to String Handling
>
> Hexadecimal strings are no longer considered numeric
>
> Strings containing hexadecimal numbers are no longer considered to be
>   numeric. For example: `<?php var_dump("0x123" == "291");` etc...

Comment: And if you absolutely must do this kind of comparison, you can wrap the hex value in [hexdec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hexdec.php) to get a decimal out.

Comment: Ah, this page was the first I looked into, can not believe I missed it! Thank you!

Comment: See also the motivating RFC, [Remove hex support in numeric strings](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_hex_support_in_numeric_strings).